# How can I delete an entry from the Windows Explorer autocomplete/drop down list?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry, autocomplete

In Windows Explorer, when you start typing a location in the address bar (or click on it's drop down menu), there's a list of autocomplete entries that automatically shows up. How can you delete an entry from that list?

[image: Windows Explorer autocomplete drop down list]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The list is kept in the Windows Registry, so to delete entries from the list:

1. Start -> type "regedit" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\TypedPaths`
3. The entries will show up as "url1", "url2"..."url15". Delete any entries you'd like, and you can use Ctrl+Click and/or Shift+Click to select and delete multiple at a time.

[image: Windows Explorer autocomplete drop down list delete entry registry edit]

Comment: The Names have to be renamed in sequence for them all to appear in the typed path box.