# Where do suggestions of file explorer address bar come from?

Tags: windows-explorer, address-bar

**Suggestions appearing when typing in the address bar of Windows file explorer**

[image: IMG:]

**Question:** from where does Windows10 get the suggestions for the address bar in the file explorer? as shown in the picture.

**Goal:** adding shortcuts/aliases so that I can access folder locations from the address bar.

This is especially helpful when you're browsing and want to get quickly to the downloads or one drive, etc...

**My research**: it's possible to delete the entries that Windows saves for suggestions. (Look at this [Superuser question.](https://superuser.com/questions/573317/how-can-i-delete-an-entry-from-the-windows-explorer-autocomplete-drop-down-list))

**UPDATE2**: It's possible to [add a custom protocol](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/332206/custom-url-protocol-for-invoking-application) that works as a shortcut. So you can directly type: "photographs" for example to get to your photograph folder.

Comment: When you refer to alias are you referring to something like `%LocalAppData%` or `%UserProfile%`?

Comment: No, it's like "Research", "Photographs", etc... Try typing "downloads" in the address bar, and immediately a suggestion will appear. I want something similar like this but for other locations.

Comment: I suspect File Explorer search is attempting to autocomplete the word, based on the contents, of the folder you are in.  If you were to navigate to a different directory different suggestions would be offer.  The only alternative is that it's not autocomplete but your recent search history (difficult to tell from your single screenshot)

Comment: Are you running 1909 or 2004?

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean? I have Windows 10 latest update.

Comment: It seems like File Explorer does as you say, and here's my question: can I add shortcuts to the root folder so that I can access it quickly? i.e: Alt+D Ctrl+A {filename} gets me to the location of {filename}?

Comment: What you describe isn't a shortcut.  `Desktop`, `Documents`, and `Downloads` are all default user profile directories, and there registry keys that exist, that indicate where those directories are.  That is the way File Explorer is able to know where the folders are, the behavior autocomplete feature, works for the contents of any folder.  **You won't be able to define a keyboard shorcut to do what you want.  File Explorer does not support that functionality**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108852/discussion-between-avidseeker-and-ramhound).